# Moving a project between directories giving errors

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm new to Xamarin, and am playing with creating a new Android App.  If I create an app in:

```
c:\dev\MyApp
```

Then the default template for VS compiles fine. However, if I create an app in a deeper directory, I get a series of errors. My first guess was that it was caused by dashes in the directory name (hence the above experiment).

My latest error is, if I create a new app (which compiles fine in the above directory - it's just the default template) in a deeper directory (no dashes). I get the following error:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2019\Preview\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(3184,2):
>   error : Could not find a part of the path
>   'AccessibilityManagerCompat_TouchExplorationStateChangeListenerImplementor.class'.

I can't find the file it's looking for, or where it's referenced. Is there an Android / Xamarin limit based on number of characters of the full path, or some other possible explanation for this?

Comment: There is a limit to the total path length.  How long is the full path of the directory, and how long is the name of your project?

Comment: The path is 105 chars and the project name another 32.  I couldn't find any reference to limits.  I did find something saying that Linux had a 255 char limit, but that obviously doesn't apply here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably running into path length limits.  Windows has a limit of 260 characters for the full path of a file.  The Android project for a Xamarin.Forms can generate very deep directory structures, and your solution name can be repeated 3 or 4 times at various levels.  So a base path length of 105, plus 3*32=96 gets you to 201 characters already. Add in other elements of file names, and it will easily blow right past 260 characters. And unfortunately, the error messages you get are very cryptic, basically just very odd build breaks.

So the upshot is that it really helps to have a short path to the root of your solution, plus keep the solution name to a shorter length, I find < 20 characters is pretty safe when working with the default Xamarin.Forms templates.  But I also keep the root directory path length shorter as well.

The alternative that works is to do some renaming of the defaults that Visual Studio gives you.  For instance, if you create a Xamarin.Forms solution called MyApplication, you'll end up with with directories like:

```
MyApplication\MyApplication\MyApplication.Android\<more stuff here>
```

You can shorten it to something like:

```
MyApp\src\Android\<more stuff here>
```

And the solution will still be called MyApplication.sln. But it does require some manual work in doing this renaming, but can work if you need it to.